# Wrong additional parameters in $.ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome, get

I'm trying to call a web service to get some data. I need pass this URL in a GET method:

```
http://localhost/ecosat/ws/api.php?t=vw_motorista
```

But, when I look in Chrome Developer Tools, the link is:

```
http://localhost/ecosat/ws/api.php?t=vw_motorista&_=1397500899753
```

I'm not passing this parameter: `&_=1397500899753`

With this additional parameter, I received a 500 error. I can't change the web service to handle this.

What's going on? Is Chrome is changing my code?

This my Ajax

```
function get(pURL, pToken) {
    var ret = null;

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        timeout: globalTimeOut,
        cache: false,
        url: pURL,
        headers: {"Token": pToken},
        error: function(request, status, error) {
            ret = null;
        },
        success: function(data) {
            ret = data;
        }
    });
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: you'll need to show us your code before we can diagnose it. A fiddle would be nice

Comment: Make sure cache : false. jQuery  automatically adds a timestamp to the end of the URL for you, making sure that ajax requests are never cached when we use cache: true

Comment: @Tushar it's the other way around: `cache: false` adds the `_` param, `cache: true` doesn't.

Comment: Yes, got confused, just remove the cache parameter if you dont need it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably using `cache: false` setting in your ajax query. It adds a `_` parameter with a timestamp value, to make sure that your ajax call doesn't get cached by the browser.

Remove this setting, if you don't need it. But if you need make sure caching is disabled, you could try two things:

add your own parameter with a timestamp to your query, e.g. `{ts: new Date.getTime()}`, or

if possible, add headers to the web server response. [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/making-sure-a-web-page-is-not-cached-across-all-browsers)

Comment: Please explain what should the OP do instead.

Comment: Why would him adding his own parameter instead of using the cache property be any different?

Comment: maybe it was the underscore character that caused the problem on the server side, so i thought trying a parameter with a different name could work. of course i'm just guessing.

Comment: i change the cache option to true and works fine. Many thanks